# SQLBindCol fails on 64 Bit Windows with "Invalid string or buffer length"

Tags: c++, winapi, odbc

In our application we have ODBC connections. These wont work at all for thex64 version.

Calling SQLBindCol from a 64 Bit Windows program fails always with the following parameters:

```
void *dataPtr = new char[ 512 ] ;
SDWORD count = 0;
SQLBindCol( hstmt, 1, SQL_C_CHAR, dataPtr, 512, &count);
```

The astonishing thing is, that instead 512 (for BufferLength). the SQL log shows a huge number of -3689348818177884160:

```
T=1             6840-3404   ENTER SQLBindCol 
        HSTMT               0x000000000E363F40
        UWORD                        1 
        SWORD                        1 <SQL_C_CHAR>
        PTR                0x0000000000000000
        SQLLEN              -3689348818177884160
        SQLLEN *            0x000000001BA1DC82

T=1             6840-3404   EXIT  SQLBindCol  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               0x000000000E363F40
        UWORD                        1 
        SWORD                        1 <SQL_C_CHAR>
        PTR                0x0000000000000000
        SQLLEN              -3689348818177884160
        SQLLEN *            0x000000001BA1DC82 (5714869293485654016)

            DIAG [S1090] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length (0)
```

Even passing BufferLength 0 results in a huge value as shown in the SQL log. 
Compiling fir 32 Bit works without problems. 
64 Bit ACCESS drivers are installed.

Comment: You have a wrong `SQLBindCol` signature that shows under x64? Does `SQLLEN` [resolve to `INT64`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/odbc-64-bit-information?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: i now tried size_t size = sizeof(SQLLEN ); but this results in  error C2065: 'SQLLEN': undeclared identifier. Hmm..

Answer (score 0):

The problem was quite simple - but not that easy to find.

Somewhere in my include paths some older versions did exist of 
sql.h sqlext.h sqltypes.h

** (C) Copyright 1990 - 1995 By Microsoft Corp.

Long before 64 Bit systems

I found this by using the "Show Includes" Option of the MSVC compiler